# Singleton thread safe block multi threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

How to get always updated password from the below objects if two users are working parallel? One is updated and same time other user trying to read it?

```
package com.designpattern.singleton;

public class Singleton {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread threadblock1 = new Thread(new ThreadSafeBlock1());
        threadblock1.start();

        Thread threadblock2 = new Thread(new ThreadSafeBlock2());
        threadblock2.start();
    }

    static class ThreadSafeBlock1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock safeblockinit1 = ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Threadsafe Block1");
            safeblockinit1.update("password", "newpassword");
        }
    }

    static class ThreadSafeBlock2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock safeblockinit2 = ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.getInstance();
            safeblockinit2.display();
        }
    }
}

package com.designpattern.singleton;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock {
    
    private static ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock threadsafeblock;

    private Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>() {{
            put("password", "oldpassword");
    }};
  
    private ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock() {
  
    }
  
    public void update(String key, String value) {
        configMap.put(key, value);
    }
    
    public void display() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : configMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
  
    public static ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock getInstance() {
        ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock result = threadsafeblock;
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        synchronized(ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.class) {
            if (threadsafeblock == null) {
                threadsafeblock = new ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock();
            }
            return threadsafeblock;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Threadsafe Block1
Threadsafe Block2
password : password

Expected Output:
Threadsafe Block1
Threadsafe Block2
password : newpassword

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thread1 and thread2 are running simultaneously. thread1 trying to update password where as thread2 trying to read the same password. we are getting only new password sometime. I want if thread1 is updating password thread2 should wait and then try to print new password after update.

Answer (score 0):

After go through multiple site reference, we conculde that we need to lock the update method and use that lock reference in read method to check is update is currently happening or not, if yes then wait for sometime to complete update and then proceed with display. this will work only both update and display(read) method called simultaneously for multi threading.

```
package com.designpattern.singleton;

public class Singleton {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread threadblock1 = new Thread(new ThreadSafeBlock1());
        threadblock1.start();

        Thread threadblock2 = new Thread(new ThreadSafeBlock2());
        threadblock2.start();
    }

    static class ThreadSafeBlock1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock safeblockinit1 = ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.getInstance();
            System.out.println("Threadsafe Block1");
            safeblockinit1.update("password", "newpassword");
        }
    }

    static class ThreadSafeBlock2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock safeblockinit2 = ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.getInstance();
            safeblockinit2.display();
        }
    }
}

package com.designpattern.singleton;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock {
    
    private static ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock threadsafeblock;

    private islocked = false;

    private Map<String, String> configMap = new HashMap<>() {{
            put("password", "oldpassword");
    }};
  
    private ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock() {
  
    }
  
    public void update(String key, String value) {
        islocked = true;
        configMap.put(key, value);
        islocked = false;
    }
    
    public void display() {
        while (islocked) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : configMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" : "+entry.getValue());
        }
    }
  
    public static ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock getInstance() {
        ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock result = threadsafeblock;
        if (result != null) {
            return result;
        }
        synchronized(ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock.class) {
            if (threadsafeblock == null) {
                threadsafeblock = new ConfigManagerWithThreadSafeBlock();
            }
            return threadsafeblock;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Threadsafe Block1
Threadsafe Block2
password : newpassword